# MaskedTextBox Interativo para Numero de Celular

Tags: c#

Tenho um *MaskedTextBox* em meu sistema com o seguinte formato `(xx) 9xxxx-xxxx` para celulares que tenham o dígito 9 a mais, mas em alguns estados não possuem esse dígito a mais ficando assim `(xx) xxxx-xxxx`.

Como faço para a `Mascara` ser interativa para acrescentar um dígito a mais ou a menos?

Comment: Que eu saiba o nono dígito já foi implementado em todo o Brasil

Answer (score 0):

Você vai ter que usar o String.Format. No seu caso, você só precisa pegar o conteúdo da sua TextBox e alterar o formato.

vai ficar mais ou menos deste jeito:

```
long cel = Convert.ToInt64(txt.Text);
string celFormatado= String.Format(@"{(00)\0000-0000}", cel );
txt.Text = celFormatado;
```